# Database backend for swift app: BaaS vs JSon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, database, parse-platform

Previous knowledge: intermediate level of Rails and Ruby.
I want to start programming IOS apps in swift as I think they will be in place for at least the next 5 years.

I already have a MySql Database setup via my Linode.

My requirement: I will be using Facebook login in a simple project and need to store info in a database.

Should I use a BaaS such as Parse for my backend cloud storage or should I stick with MySql and have simple Json call via an rails app?

What advantage do I have using Parse?

Comment: spend a day with Parse - if you feel it meets your needs then it's probably a good way to go.

Comment: I've been searching a long time on the net for that. Parse has some advantages I see. You can integrate FB login easily and you can integrate push notification easily. If you want to have a rails app connected to your IOS app you will need to integrate FB SDK then the Mobile app gets fb_access_token and post it to API server to identify the user. In order to build a prototype Parse (or any BaaS) is fast and cheap, However if you need to build an entreprise app (like Tinder) you are much better off building your own backend via Rails/PHP/node.js or whatever server side technology.

Comment: hmm.... things like that can change pretty quick. I have never written an app backed by Parse since I do rails coding. I feel like I could probably do it just as quickly myself as in Parse.

Comment: Finally I took your advice and hard coded my iOS app to connect to my rails app via json. So the secret is simply do make an API with rails/ruby/whatever and then make an API call via the iOS app through a simple function. In my case my rails app is already hooked up to MySql so I updated it via json through rails. No bother with Parse.

Comment: cool - that's the basic model; use something like AFNetworking if you want although NSURLSession gets you very far. Parse does provide nice add-ons like Facebook auth and super easy notifications. You can check out AFNetworking's sample project for how they do it.